# javascript for loop and put into a new array

Tags: javascript

Here is the code i have:

```
let testp = {
  value: ''
}
let data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  testp.value = i;
  data.push(testp);
}

console.log(data)
```

The data return is:

```
[ { value: 4 },
  { value: 4 },
  { value: 4 },
  { value: 4 },
  { value: 4 } ]
```

why? I think the result is like this:

```
[ { value: 0 },
  { value: 1 },
  { value: 2 },
  { value: 3 },
  { value: 4 } ]
```

Comment: assigning testp.value inside loop was causing the problem

Comment: `testp` is a reference to the javascript object; when you call `data.push(testp)`, you're merely adding to the array another reference to that same object. not a copy of the current state of the object

Comment: You're getting `4` for every value, because JavaScript passes objects by reference, not by value. Thus you're modifying the same object on every iteration of the loop, not a different object.

Comment: @fubar—well, it's actually always by value, just that for objects (or [*non-primitives*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-4.3.2)), the value held by a variable is a reference.

Comment: Probably a duplicate of [*javascript assignment operator array*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13050279/javascript-assignment-operator-array).

Comment: you are editing the same address space. Objects are copied by reference.

Comment: @RobG the phrase 'copy by reference' is a common expression intending that  the memory address is the only thing copied. There was no need to boast your arrogance.

Answer (score 2):

You're pushing a reference to the object `testp` into the array 5 times, editing the value of `value` each time.

Here's another example:

```
let foo = { 'a': 1 };
let bar = [foo, foo, foo];
foo.a = 2;
console.log(foo[2]);
// 2
```

The array `bar` contains three *references* to `foo`. Changing the content of the object will change the content of the object everywhere it is referenced.

If you want new objects you have to create them somewhere. For example:

```
// Function that constructs the new objects
let foo = (value) => { return { "value": value } };
let data = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
   data.push(foo(i));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Assigning testp.value inside the loop was causing the problem.Instead you could do

```js
let testp = {
  value: ''
}
let data = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  data.push({
    value: i
  });
}

console.log(data)
```

Comment: Can you explain the reason why assigning inside of the loop is causing the problem?